# Convergence of a tetration series

Tags: sequences-and-series, special-functions, exponential-sums

Let $0<a\neq 1$ be a fixed real number and denote by **$a^{ \frac{x}{}}:=\mbox{uxp}_a(x)$** the ultra exponential function (ultra power) that is a unique extension of tetration (and also its linear approximation). One can see the uniqueness theorem in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration and the paper :**Ultra power and ultra exponential functions** (http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/10652460500422247).

Note that 
$$ \mbox{uxp}_a(x)=\exp^{[x]}_a (a^{(x)})=\exp^{[x+1]}_a((x))=
\begin{cases}
\vdots \;\;\;\;\; & \; \vdots\\
\log_a(x+2) \;\;\;\;\;  & \; -2<x<-1 \\ 1+x
\;\;\;\;\;  & \; -1\leq x<0 \\ a^x \;\;\;\;\;  & \; 0\leq
x<1 \\ a^{a^{x-1}} \;\;\;\;\;  & \; 1\leq x<2 \\ \vdots
\;\;\;\;\; & \; \vdots
\end{cases}$$
where $[x]$ is the largest integer not exceeding $x$, $(x)=x-[x]$ (the 
fractional part of $x$), $\exp_a (x)=a^x$, $\exp(x)=\exp_e(x)=e^x$.

**(?)** Now, is it true that the following series is convergent for $a=(\frac{1}{e})^e$
and all $x>-2$ ?
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a^{\frac{n}{}}-a^{\frac{n+x}{}} 
$$

Comment: I think that "linear interpolation" is worth to be discussed elsewhere. "Tetration" and "Ultra" as buzzword/eye-catcher... (-1) (Possibly http://go.helms-net.de/math/tetdocs/ComparisionOfInterpolations.pdf (pg. 6) is of interest here)

Comment: Yes, by a telescoping argument this must converge.